# redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 393 redis-replication-0001-001.xxx.amazonaws.com:6379

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster, redis-py, spark-redis

I have AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster with 2 nodes.
I am using redis-py lib for python (version 5.0.1)
Seeing following error in pyspark app:

```
  │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 4946, in hget                                                                                                                                                 │
    │     return self.execute_command("HGET", name, key)                                                                                                                                                                                         │
    │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 536, in execute_command                                                                                                                                              │
    │     return conn.retry.call_with_retry(                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
    │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry                                                                                                                                                │
    │     return do()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
    │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 537, in <lambda>                                                                                                                                                     │
    │     lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(                                                                                                                                                                                             │
    │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 513, in _send_command_parse_response                                                                                                                                 │
    │     return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)                                                                                                                                                                              │
    │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 553, in parse_response                                                                                                                                               │
    │     response = connection.read_response()                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
    │   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 524, in read_response                                                                                                                                            │
    │     raise response                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
    │ redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 393 redis-replication-0001-001.xxx.amazonaws.com:6379
```

Code, giving MOVED error:

```
import redis

class redis_conn_pool:

    def __init__(self, host, password, username):
        self.host_ = host
        self.pd_ = password
        self.user_ = username

    def connect(self):
        pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host=self.host_,
                                    port=6379,
                                    password=self.pd_,
                                    username=self.user_,
                                    connection_class=redis.SSLConnection,
                                    decode_responses = True,
                                    )
        conn = redis.RedisCluster(connection_pool=pool, host = self.host_, reinitialize_steps=1)

        self.conn = conn
```

Tried different values for reinitialize_steps.

Following code is working:

```
import redis

class redis_conn:

    def __init__(self, host, password, username):
        self.host_ = host
        self.port_ = 6379
        self.pd_ = password
        self.user_ = username

    def connect(self):
        conn = redis.RedisCluster(host=self.host_,
                            port=self.port_,
                            password=self.pd_,
                            username=self.user_,
                            ssl=True,
                            decode_responses = True,
                            skip_full_coverage_check=True)
        self.conn = conn
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work with ConnectionPool?

Answer (score 1):

A Redis cluster shards your data over all nodes in your cluster. `ConnectionPool` is not cluster-aware, and can only connect to one node. When data resides in another node, it gives back a reference to that node. If you provide a `ConnectionPool`, I suspect that `RedisCluster` only uses that node even though there are other nodes in the cluster.

`RedisCluster` creates a cluster-aware client and performes the redirection behind the scenes and can therefore return data from all nodes in the cluster. If you create a `RedisCluster` without a `ConnectionPool`, it automatically creates the connection pools needed.

To avoid establishing new connections, keep the client alive in your code. Here is a [quote](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/new-cluster-mode-support-in-redis-py/) on how pooling works internally in `Redis-py`:

> Connection pools: RedisCluster internally holds a Redis client instance to communicate with each of the shards in the cluster. Each of these Redis client instances maintains a pool of connections to its shard, which allows it to reuse connections when communicating with the shard. This saves the performance penalty of establishing a new connection for each command.

Comment: Thanks. So, there is no way to use a ConnectionPool with the RedisCluster class? Can I only use it with the Redis class? What should I do if I don't want to create a new connection pool each time I create a connection using RedisCluster? (I mean if I need to run it multiple times within the application.)

Comment: @leotim In normal situations you don't need to keep track of the pool, only your client. I have updated the answer with a bit more context.

Comment: thank you @duckoak for sharing https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/new-cluster-mode-support-in-redis-py/. It's unfortunate that I didn't come across this page earlier. It looks like I can make up for it by using Read-Only Mode in RedisCluster constructor. (I need only read ops)